# how to set "Back Button" , closing activies except main activity in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

first of all sorry for my english. i am new at android and working on app. 
my app has 8 activities and they usually starting by click and 
like this, activity1-> 2->3->4->5->6->7->activity8 .
as usual, 
when i press the back button 7 times  and it closes activities  act8 to act1. if i am at activty1 back button closes the app.  i want to make a alerdiaolog there to alert me like  "it is your last activity!!".  but when i use **public void onBackPressed()**  command to show diaolog such as" are u sure to exit ?"  ,  it is not only prevent app closing,  it is also prevent closing the other activies,  for example if i am at the 8th activity i cant go back to 7th activity,  app shows me alert dialog "are u sure to exit ?"

to sum up;
- where should i put the **public void onBackPressed()** code ,  if i want to prevent only closing app except activies?
- can i use code like this , if(myactivity is the lastone or main activity ) { "are sure to exit the app ?"}

Sorry for language again, thank you for your interest.

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: `onBackPressed()` it's a override method. Don't need to write in code. You can write this method in activity 1 for your alert dialog.

Comment: are you using any BaseActivity kind of mechanism?

Comment: Sorry, just to understand better: Do you want activity 1 to ask the user if they are sure they want to exit, and activity 2-8 to have the normal back behaviour?

Comment: yes, i am using baseActivity. when i override "onBackPressed()" for baseactivity to show alert dialog , all the activities are showing alert dialog when i press back  button.

Comment: @Zee yes , i want that.

Comment: than just remove this code from your baseActivity and write in your firstActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep `onBackPressed()` as it is in your activities **2 to 8** and in activity 1 override `onBackPressed()` as below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not finishing your first activity whenever you stat new activity this solution works.
In last activitiy's onBackpress() write following

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //show your alert here and in alert's conform you should call finish()
    }
```